# Linkedin API - Search post by keyword

Tags: php, search, linkedin-api

I try to connect my web application with Linkedin through Linkedin API for PHP. 
Is there any way to search for people's publications by keyword using this?

If this can be done, I haven't found the way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think they have this native so they can avoid scrapping.

You can extract all publications https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/get-network-updates-and-statistics-api
and process the results and leave only the ones that have the keyword you are searching for.

Comment: url redirects - does that mean LinkedIn has deprecated this API?

Comment: I think this is the new url: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/network-update-social-actions#retrieve-a-summary-of-social-actions

Comment: Note though that these are not "posts on all of LinkedIn" but rather only "posts from people in the currently authenticated user would have seen". I will admit The documentation is very confusingly organized and presented.