# Is it possible to search LinkedIn Posts with Linkedin Api - able to authenticate

Tags: linkedin-api

Using python, I am trying to search LinkedIn and want to get results. I am able to authenticate and got the access token also. As per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592675/linkedin-api-search-post-by-keyword) the api might be available .
However, when I explored this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/page-statistics?view=li-lms-unversioned&tabs=http)  I am not able find relevant API which gives search results on public posts. Most of APIs are related to specific URN or specific posts.

Does LinkedIn has any API to search ?

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn does not support public post search. So I had searched posts using RPA

Comment: Hi what is RPA? I am trying to do this too